# Use regex to match regextest(dontcare,dontcare,true)

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to look for all function calls (c++, but not important) where the function is called with 3 parameters and the last parameter has a certain value.

for example I want to search for all calls to regextest where it is called with 3 parameters and the third parameter is 'true'

```
regextest(aaa,bbb,true) : OK
regextest(aaa,ccc,false) : NOK, third parameter is not 'true'
regextest(aaa,bbb,true,false) : NOK four parameters are used
```

Comment: Need more info. Can we be certain that commas occur within the function call only as argument separators? Or could they be part of an argument as if `regextest(foo, "bar,baz", bam)`?

Comment: If you _don't_ have commas appearing besides their role as parameter separators, then try the following pattern: `\([^,]+,[^,]+,\s*false\s*\)` ... it seems to work well [here](https://regex101.com/r/fFjCnr/1).

Comment: In this case the commas only appear as separators

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters can't contain any commas themselves, use

```
regextest\([^(),]+,[^(),]+,true\)
```

**Explanation:**

```
regextest\( # Match "regextest("
[^(),]+     # Match one or more characters except parens/commas
,           # Match a comma
[^(),]+     # (see above)
,true\)     # Match ",true)"
```

Note that whitespace is significant when matching a regex - you may need to use `,\s*true\s*)` in the last part of the regex if there could be whitespace around `true`.